# Not found in annotated query error with @Query

Tags: jpa, spring-data-rest

I am using spring data with REST. I have a table country and an Entity corresponding to it called Country.java

I have annotated my method in CountryRepositopry as

```
public interface CountryRepository extends Repository<Country, Short> {

    @RestResource(path = "bycode3")
        @Query("select c from Country c where c.codeAlpha3=?1 and c.active=1")
        Country findCountryByCodeAlpha3(@Param("code") String countryCode);
 }
```

I am getting following exception while starting tomcat-

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract com.persistence.entity.common.Country com.persistence.repository.CountryRepository.findCountryByCodeAlpha3(java.lang.String) but parameter 'code' not found in annotated query 'select c from Country c where c.codeAlpha3=?1 and c.active=1'!
```

Comment: use `:` instead of `?`

Answer (score 18):

I got the fixed

Query needs be modified as

```
@Query("select c from Country c where c.codeAlpha3=:code and c.active=1")
```

Instead of **?1** it should be **:code**

Answer (score 12):

The text `xxx` in `@Param("xxx")` must be used in Query `value`.

Answer (score 2):

just an add-on to existing answers

```
@Query("select c from Country c where c.codeAlpha3=: code and c.active=1")
```

don't put space between ":code" as ":  code"
or else you will get error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using @Param annotation, you should use same as ur entity class parameter and also use it same in "`(@Param("code") String countryCode)`" also:

```
public interface CountryRepository extends Repository<Country, Short> {

    @RestResource(path = "bycode3")
        @Query("select c from Country c where c.codeAlpha3=?1 and c.active=1")
        Country findCountryByCodeAlpha3(@Param("code") String countryCode);
 }
```

According to this, it should be changed like this:

```
@RestResource(path = "bycode3")
    @Query("select c from Country c where c.codeAlpha3=?1 and c.active=1")
    Country findCountryByCodeAlpha3(@Param("codeAlpha3") String countryCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but
always make sure that the string value in @Param("code") is the same as the named variable value you want to use in your query.

```
@RestResource(path = "bycode3")
    @Query("select c from Country where c.codeAlpha3=:code and c.active=1")
    Country findCountryByCodeAlpha3(@Param("code") String countryCode);
```